# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.tugas, PID: 12670

Tags: java, android-studio

I just want to send data from activity1 to activity 2 using text input, where activity 1 makes data input and activity 2 displays data from activity 1,I have followed the full youtube tutorial but still the error and the error is no warning in the line of code, I don't understand if this is an error from android studio or a code writing error, here it is written :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tugas, PID: 12670
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tugas/com.example.tugas.dua}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

---

this my activity1 page  `MainActivity.java` code:

```
package com.example.tugas;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    EditText et;
    String st;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.kirim);
        et = findViewById(R.id.test);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,dua.class);
                st = et.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("Value",st);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

here my `activity_main.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="2sp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type Something" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/kirim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/test"
        android:text="submit"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

this is my second activity `dua.java` code:

```
package com.example.tugas;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class dua extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    String st;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dua);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.test);
        st = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Value");
        textView.setText(st);
    }
}
```

---

here my second activity layout `activity_dua.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".dua">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Value"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

this my `AndroidManifest.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.tugas">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Tugas"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".dua"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Simply.You don't define the TextView object **id** In the dua **(Activity.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".dua">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test" <--
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Value"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```